# how to implement a shopping cart

Tags: e-commerce, webserver, shopping-cart

Lets say that i have a web service model in which a customer can choose a product, add it into their shopping cart, browse other products on the web site, return to the shopping cart and buy some of the items, redirected to the ssl session, pay the amount and then return back to the shopping cart to buy/delete more items from it.

My question is how do web servers implement the shopping carts. My guess is for each user, the server side can cache the shopping cart details and later send it back to the browser. But when the user is redirected to the ssl session, how to servers maintain the identity of the user (and their shopping cart) without actually having the user to create an account on the website.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

With [sessions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29#HTTP_session_token) (the browser keeps the same session ID when the payment processor redirects it to the "payment complete" page on the original site, then the data from the session is easily retrieved) or [IPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Payment_Notification) custom variables, such as a cart ID (the initial payment processor request contains a cart ID, which is stored in the database, then the IPN mentions the same cart ID, which is then retrieved from the database).